# Update serialized data

Tags: system-config, grid-serlization

I have this module adding "packing stations"
In "my account" i want to be able to change the users active station.
Therefore i need to push the "userid" into selected "code".

My array when unserialized looks like:

```
Array
(
    [_1478435099391_391] => Array
        (
            [user] => 9
            [code] => #PACKINGSTATION 1
        )

    [_1478608807336_336] => Array
        (
            [user] => 100
            [code] => #PACKINGSTATION 2
        )

)
```

How can i push a new user into packingstation 2 forexample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily use core php function [array_push](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-push.php) . Suppose that you want to add new entry this array then you can easily do this like.

```
$test=unserialize($serialized_data);

if(is_array($test)){
array_push($test,$newData);
}
```

`$serialized_data` is your previous data.

Where `$newData` is new entry and it must be `array`. If its not array then you can easily convert into array by doing  `$newData=unserialize($serialized_data);`

Comment: But how do i save it to my serialized table in database then?

Comment: In core_config_data

Comment: After appending data you can again do serialize($unserilize_data) then save into core_config_data

Comment: Can you tell me why i get error in this? 

`$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
        $query = "UPDATE {core_config_data} SET value = '{$valuesToSave}' WHERE path = 'packing_station/printerkey/users'";
        $writeConnection->query($query);`

Comment: Srry updated it, but still doesnt save :-( just getting magento error

Comment: post your whole code Into the question so people can see @BrittanyMoore

Comment: Owh i just had to put core_config_data into a variable, then it all worked. Thank you! you're my hero today :-)

Comment: Glad to hear that It works for you :) @BrittanyMoore Enjoy Magento